# Dragon NaturallySpeaking takes a few secs to transcribe the first utterance after turning the mic on, but is fast to transcribe the other utterances

Tags: windows, dragon-naturally-speaking, speech-recognition

Dragon NaturallySpeaking takes a few seconds to transcribe the first utterance after turning the microphone on, but is fast (<0.5s) to transcribe the following utterances, as long as I don't turn off the microphone.

How can I make Dragon transcribe the first utterance faster?

I don't see any background process that would explain the slow transcription of the first utterance. The delay occurs for the first utterance after the microphone has been turned on. Note that if I turn on the microphone, wait a few seconds, and then say something, in that case there is no transcription delay. It seems that the first few seconds after the microphone has been turned on are being used by Dragon for doing some calibration or something else (I don't see any outstanding CPU activity).

My setup is as follows: I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I have an Audio-Technica AT2035 microphone connected to a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 USB Audio interface, which is connected to my computer through USB and which I use for Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

---

The issue is not present when placing the microphone to sleep:

[image]

but is present when turning off the microphone:

[image]

The issue is not present when I use my other microphone + USB interface ([Sennheiser ME 3-EW headset EW microphone](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B002FOFW52/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) + [Buddy USB 7G Sound Pod (with FilteredAudio)](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B005X99WCA/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1))

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=33222